# dimple.js example chart not loading

Tags: html, dimple.js

I am having trouble  loading the example code from dimple.js for the following chart:
http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_storyboard_control

The only change I made is to save it as a .csv instead of .tsv.
The code (index.html) is saved as:
"C:\website\public\index.html"
and the datafile is saved as: 
"C:\website\public\data\example_data.csv"

Any reasons this wouldn't load?

Note: dimple example data file can be retrieved from: http://dimplejs.org/data/example_data.tsv
My code in index.html is exactly as the code from the dimple example page
except for the reference to the data file in line 7, I use:

d3.csv("/data/example_data.csv", function (data) {

Answer (score 0):

When referencing the .tsv file instead of .csv there is no problem.

StillNot certain why the file format mattered for this, however.